# How to delete joined tables filtered by date in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to delete old data out of multiple tables that reference each other, but those tables do not have one common column among all of them. This database is more of a top down setup where one tables column will reference a subsequent table and then that subsequent table will reference another table below that. I was able to select all the data I want in the code below but I can't get it to delete my selection.

```
delete from Batches 
where exists (select *
              from Batches 
              full outer join Rolls on Batches.id = Rolls.batch_id
              full outer join RollSessions on Rolls.id = RollSessions.roll_id 
              full outer join Results on RollSessions.id = Results.rollSession_id
              full outer join Dimensions on Results.id = Dimensions.result_id 
              full outer join DimensionTols on Results.id = DimensionTols.result_id
              full outer join Defects on Results.id = Defects.result_id
              Where Batches.created_at < '2019-01-09 16:43:51.513')'
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are different?

Comment: Your query logically looks like `delete from Batches Where created_at < '2019-01-09 16:43:51.513';`. Buit it is practically equvalent to `delete from Batches;`.

Comment: why the exists with joins? if you have key references in other tables, you need to execute multiple delete statements from "leaf tables" inwards. in other words, delete the records in the table which no further key dependencies, then work your way up to the main table containing the main keys used. we don't know your structure, so you just need to map out the dependencies, and do deletes in the right order. or you could whack all the key relationsships, delete what you want, then re-instate the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make several DELETE sentences, one for each table, starting with the table at the bottom. Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Defects 
WHERE Defects.result_id IN
(SELECT Defects.result_id
FROM Batches 
Full Outer Join Rolls on Batches.id = Rolls.batch_id
Full Outer Join RollSessions on Rolls.id = RollSessions.roll_id 
Full Outer Join Results on RollSessions.id = Results.rollSession_id
Full Outer Join Dimensions on Results.id = Dimensions.result_id 
Full Outer Join DimensionTols on Results.id = DimensionTols.result_id
Full Outer Join Defects on Results.id = Defects.result_id
Where Batches.created_at < '2019-01-09 16:43:51.513')

DELETE FROM DimensionTols 
WHERE DimensionTols.result_id IN
(SELECT DimensionTols.result_id
FROM Batches 
Full Outer Join Rolls on Batches.id = Rolls.batch_id
Full Outer Join RollSessions on Rolls.id = RollSessions.roll_id 
Full Outer Join Results on RollSessions.id = Results.rollSession_id
Full Outer Join Dimensions on Results.id = Dimensions.result_id 
Full Outer Join DimensionTols on Results.id = DimensionTols.result_id        
Where Batches.created_at < '2019-01-09 16:43:51.513')

DELETE FROM Dimensions 
WHERE Dimensions.result_id IN
(SELECT Dimensions.result_id
FROM Batches 
Full Outer Join Rolls on Batches.id = Rolls.batch_id
Full Outer Join RollSessions on Rolls.id = RollSessions.roll_id 
Full Outer Join Results on RollSessions.id = Results.rollSession_id
Full Outer Join Dimensions on Results.id = Dimensions.result_id                         
Where Batches.created_at < '2019-01-09 16:43:51.513')

DELETE FROM Results 
WHERE Results.rollSession_id IN
(SELECT Results.rollSession_id
FROM Batches 
Full Outer Join Rolls on Batches.id = Rolls.batch_id
Full Outer Join RollSessions on Rolls.id = RollSessions.roll_id 
Full Outer Join Results on RollSessions.id = Results.rollSession_id                         
Where Batches.created_at < '2019-01-09 16:43:51.513')
```

You continue like this until you get to the last Delete statement. It would be:

```
DELETE FROM Batches WHERE Batches.created_at < '2019-01-09 16:43:51.513'
```